# How can I remove spaces in my web layout?

Tags: html, css

On my web page, I have spaces between the rows (each section of the page is it's own row). As seen below in the responses, I had "Colspec" tags where my "Col-md" tags should've gone. I also didn't have the 'row' tag in there. Fixed those, thanks to those that helped. I've tried replacing the 'colspec' tags with the 'col-md-12' tags. This gave me spaces on the sides of each row/column, which I also don't like. I have since pulled out the 'col-med' tags. The rows now go all the way to each side. Great. However, I still have spaces between each row.

In an attempt to be more clear, here is the code for one of my rows:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="classWithPad2">
    <h1 class="customfont">TEXT</h1>
<div class="classWithPad">
<p class="customfont">TEXT<span tabindex="0" data-term="goog_20335794">TEXT<br>
               TEXT<br>
               TEXT<a href="mailto:XXX@XXXXX.com">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></a><br>
               </p>
  </div>
   <div class="classWithPad2"><h1 class="customfont">PRICES</h1>
   <div class="classWithPad">
             <p class="customfont">TEXT<br>
              TEXT</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Each row is coded similarly.

[SITE IS HERE](http://ZenandStoneMassage.com/)

Comment: Got code? Please post a code sample or a link to a code sample so people can tinker with it. A link tot he site isn't the same thing.

Comment: Did you try removing extra margins or padding on the element ? Try setting your css like so margin:0; padding;0 and see if that works.

Comment: Well your markup isn't following Bootstrap at all. Should be `container > row > column`.

Comment: Thanks. Like I said, I'm really new at this type of site. Built my sites much differently in the past.

Answer (score 1):

What does `colspec-md-12` do in your HTML? You have assigned `colspec-md-12` as class to many divs. **Replace that with `col-md-12` which is a bootstrap class**, which will remove the blank spaces.

As others mentioned in their comments, your markup is not at all valid.

For the bootstrap to work correctly, the `col-md-12` class should be nested inside a `.row` class, which itself should  be nested inside a `.container`class.

Please see the [official page of bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for more details

Comment: That actually isn't a solution because the whole site isn't following proper markup. Just applying the correct Boostrap class won't solve the issue if the parent containers aren't there. Especially since there aren't any rows.

Comment: A downvote quikly is not right @Aibrean. I'm editing my post. I just gave the right solution at first and editing the post that mentions the improvements that he needs to do in his code. Atleast we are here to help others, not to downvote..!!

Comment: Post a complete answer first. I can't assume you'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues here

One, the class should be `col-md-12` instead of `colspec-md-12`

Second of all, the `col-md-12` class should be nested inside a `.row` class, which should itself be nested inside a `.container` or `.container-fluid` class. It should look something like this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The space between sections indicates that there is a margin between these sections. Probably has to do with these lines of code

```
.classWithPad { 
    margin:30px;  
}

.classWithPad2 { 
    margin:15px;  
}
```

It looks like you are confusing margin with padding. I'd change the margin property to padding property, which allows space at the end of the section, instead of between sections.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this and let you know. I think you are right on the padding thing and not sure how I got the colspec thing in there. I tried swapping those and it added more space, this time on the sides. But I haven't tried the other things that you recommended. Will have a look.

Comment: Okay, I've replaced my colspec tags, went through and checked my div tags (they lurk...), and made sure that everything had a container and a row.  Things are still wonky. Now there is padding on the sides as well as in between the rows. To address a comment above, the reason I didn't post code was because it was seemingly the entire page giving me a problem and I really didn't want to post all of the code.
Here is where it is now: http://zenandstonemassage.com/TEST/      I think the code is cleaner, but darned if I can find that spacing issue. I'd think it'd be in the CSS, but I have looked.